# trying to make "a dance of fire and ice" and having trouble with vectors

Tags: c#

Before I start anything I'm a newb to coding, so please be generous in my mistakes, and I'm very open to any suggestions or feedback so don't hesitate to do so.

```
public class rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 pivotPosition;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.back, 20 * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) 
        {
            Vector3 pivotPosition = GameObject.Find("Sphere").transform.position;
            transform.RotateAround(Vector3.pivotPosition, Vector3.back, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

the above codes are what I've done so far, and I think it's basically a code that rotates an object, and when the user presses the space bar the pivot would change.

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) 
{
    Vector3 pivotPosition = GameObject.Find("Sphere").transform.position;
    transform.RotateAround(Vector3.pivotPosition, Vector3.back, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

my problem aroused from this part of the code. This code in my belief is made to change to the pivot of the object to the sphere, but there was an error in the Vector3.pivotPosition. If anyone knows the solution or have any idea please tell me!!

Comment: Vector3 is a struct in Unity framework, looks like you are not familiar to C#. Structs are data types which have their own properties and fields. There is not such property in Vector3 struct named pivotPosition. So as I guess you need to change Vector3.pivotPosition with just your declared variable named pivorPosition and it might work

Comment: That's why you are getting an error, which is compiler error in C# side.